# HTML5 sse inside a few ajax request (sync)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html, server-sent-events

my web app has one listener (`sse` html5), this `sse` always run in background.

`php` listener code similar to :

```
while(true)
{ 
sleep(1);
// Something is done
}
```

user for send action to server send a few `ajax` request.

when listener run in background `ajax` request failed

how fix this?

Comment: How did it "fail"?  Do you have an error message?

Comment: when listener run background send `ajax` request after 30 second (`php` limit time) fail request. when close listener `ajax` request show output.

Comment: Please share this output, and share the specific request failed message.  Also, please put these in your original question, not in the comments.

Comment: When that code is called from the server it is via Apache and the php module? And when run in background you start it using php-cli from a cronjob? How long do you expect it to run, when run in the background? More than 30 seconds? (Is this on Windows or Linux?)  (As another commenter said, it would be best to expand out your question with this kind of information.)